# File field ... not loading

Tags: file-uploads, fieldtype

I updated my installation of EE to 5.2.3 and now my file fields say "...loading" but do not load. Other fields work. I tried a fresh install but the same thing happens. I am wondering if someone might be able to offer me some advice.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a [similar issue](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/41268/fresh-ee-5-5-2-install-javascript-error-that-breaks-the-admin-control-panel-pl) a while back. I don't know what your console is saying but if it's returning a 406 error it's probably an issue with Mod_Security preventing your scripts from rendering. Check out the link I posted and see if anything looks familiar. If it does then it's a server side issue and you'll have to whitelist those actions in Mod_Security. If your site is hosted on a web hosting service then you'll have to contact their support team and resolve it that way. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Shayne.  Modsecurity was the cause and having my domains whitelisted the solution.

Comment: I'm glad you got your problem solved.